# Vaadin line chart data point symbol depending on value

Tags: charts, vaadin

I would like to display a line chart in which data point symbols would mean the wind direction.

This would mean that the symbol depends on a value in the serie. For instance a serie with value {date: "whatever", speed: 12, direction: "E"} should display a data point with Yaxis value 12 and an arrow pointing to the left (east winds)

I know I must use the MarkerSymbol, but this would mean, AFAIK, for all data points.

Is this feasible with Vaadin charts?

Thanks a lot in advance

Fran

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you retrive/make your DataSeriesItem s but, assuming you have all set, this would do the job, for example

```
for (DataSeriesItem dataSeriesItem : series.getData()) {
    if (dataSeriesItem.getY().intValue() > 66) {
        dataSeriesItem.getMarker().setSymbol(new MarkerSymbolUrl("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png"));
    } else if (dataSeriesItem.getY().intValue() > 33) {
        dataSeriesItem.getMarker().setSymbol(new MarkerSymbolUrl("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"));
    } else {
        //no changes
    }
}
```

If you can, try set this marker when you create each DateSeriesItem, so you avoid a useless iteration over your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcelloGarini! This would mean for instance having the ThemeResource url already in every DataSeriesItem prepared depending on the value, so charts does not need to do anything. I'll check with this.

Comment: You are welcome! For the URLs, maybe make some kind of enumeration, so you do not move around the whole string. Good work!